# Subsystem of system of inequalities having no solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

In the section on Carathéodory's Theorem in Theory of Linear and Integer Programming by Alexander Schrijver is stated:

> One similiarly shows, with the help of Farkas' lemma (...): if a system Ax <= b of n variables has no solution, then Ax <= b has a
>   subsystem A'x <= b' of at most n + 1 inequalities having no solution.

The meaning of the "then" part of this statement is unclear to me. It seems to me that no individual inequality can have no solution when considered in isolation, so presumably what is meant is that the subsystem as a whole has no solution. If that is the case, what is the significance of the subsystem and why does it comprise at most n + 1 inequalities?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this context, $A$ is an$\;m{\times}n\;$matrix and the variables $x,b$ represent $n$-vectors and $m$-vectors, respectively. Your job is to show that can you drop all but at most $n+1$ rows of $A$ and $b$ and the new system $A'x\le b'$ will still have no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an example will help. The system of four inequalities in $2$ variables
  $$ \eqalign{- x_1 + x_2 &\le 0 \cr
               - x_1 - x_2 & \le 0 \cr
                x_1 & \le -1\cr
                x_2 & \le 2 \cr}$$
has no solutions.  The theorem says you can take some three of these inequalities and still have no solution.  In this case, there is only one way to choose three of the inequalities and have no solution:
  $$ \eqalign{- x_1 + x_2 &\le 0 \cr
               - x_1 - x_2 & \le 0 \cr
                x_1 & \le -1\cr}$$
On the other hand, with just two of these inequalities you would always have a solution.

Comment: Yes, of course you could.  For example: $$\eqalign{x_1 + \ldots + x_n &\le -1 \cr -x_1 - \ldots - x_n & \le -1}$$

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thank you. I have deleted the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the light of the above responses the following proof can be given:

By Farkas' lemma, Ax <= b has no solution if and only if yb < 0 for each row vector y >= 0 such that yA = 0.

Thus, Ax <= b has no solution if and only if yb < 0 for each y >= 0 such that y (A b) =  (0 k), where (A b) is an m x (n + 1) matrix whose first n columns are the columns of A and whose last column contains the elements of b, and (0 k) is a row matrix whose first n elements are zero and whose last element is any number < 0.

Since y >= 0, y(A b) lies in the convex cone generated by the rows of (A b). By Carathéodory's theorem, if (0 k) = y(A b) is contained in this cone then it is contained in a cone generated by a linearly independent subset of the rows of (A b), which can have at most n + 1 elements.

The subset having at most n + 1 elements correspond to a subsystem of inequalities which has no solution if Ax <= b has no solution.